# How do I ensure that the (small) data set is replicated to all nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have a small data set `mysmall` which I need when streaming-processing a large set `mylarge`.

Right now I do

```
hadoop fs -get mysmall
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -files mysmall,myscript.py \
  -reducer ... -input mylarge -output ... \
  -mapper "python myscript.py mysmall"
```

which seems suboptimal - I collect `mysmall` from hadoop and then
redistribute it to all the nodes using the `-files` option.

It would seem that there should be a way to tell hadoop to replicate `mysmall` to all the nodes and then access it from `myscript.py` using
hadoop path.

Is it possible to do that?

PS. When I say "*small data set*", I mean a range from a single record (less than 1kB) to 200k records (4MB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the file to hdfs, it will break the files into blocks and replicate each chunk across different nodes three times (as default). In your situation, if you really have a  small file which is smaller than the default block size(128MB for Cloudera I vaguely remember). The file won't be broken and it will be sent over to three datanodes only(not distributed on every node).

You can see how the file has been broken into pieces using the url `namenodeFQDN:50070/dfshealth.jsp`, and there is an option browse the file system either on Hadoop1 or Hadoop2 environment.

To answer your question, if you run hadoop streaming, there might be mappers on every data node, which won't contain the small file locally even if you already "distribute" it using hdfs dfs put.

For you to access the file, there are four solutions.

1. The way that you are doing, which is good enough. using the `-files` flag in hdfs.
2. If the file is really small, maybe you can think about include the content in your python script instead of reading from a separate folder.
3. Actually NFS is a handy solution if you do a lot of hadoop streaming. So in your script, you can run "openfile('nfs/smallfile')", and every node is supposed to see it.
4. access the small file inside mapper directly from hdfs, maybe using `pydoop` or some other libraries, so each mapper will read the `small` form the HDFS on the fly.

There are some ideas that pop up in my mind and I have experience with the first 3 solution with success.